# Why is my list displaying empty when wrapped in react-drag-reorder tags?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to take the easy way out and use a library to implement reordering of books in a list. Unfortunately, the list displays the text for an empty list as soon as I wrap it in the  tags. I'm not sure where to look for the problem.

My cutdown code is:

```
import React, {useRef, useState, useEffect, Component} from 'react';
import BookCard from '../Book/Partials/BookCard';
import { Draggable } from "react-drag-reorder";
import CommentCard from './Partials/CommentCard';


export default function EditSeries({ auth, series, errors }) {

    const [books, setBooks] = useState({
        books: []
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        getSeriesData();
    }, []);

    function getSeriesData() {
        axios.get(route('api.series.show', {series: series}))
            .then(response => {
                response.data.series.description = response.data.series.description ? response.data.series.description : 'No Description';
                setForm(response.data.series);
                setBooks(response.data.books);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    let bookList = books.length > 0
        ? books.map((b, i) => {
            console.log(books);
            return (
                <BookCard key={b.isbn} book={b} series={form} delete={removeBook} allowAddTo={false} user={auth.user.id} />
            );
        })
        : <p>This series has no books yet.</p>;

    return (
        <Draggable>
            <img src="/storage/nocover.png" />
            {bookList}
        </Draggable>
    )
}
```

and the BookCard component is:

```
import { Head, useForm } from '@inertiajs/react';
import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton';
import React, {useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/react';
import Image from './Image';
import Switch from '@/Components/Switch';
import Checkbox from '@/Components/Checkbox';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {faPerson} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import {faBars} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faTrashCan } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

export default function BookCard(props) {
    console.log(props);

    const hasSeries = (props.series.id != null );
    const isOwner = (props.series ? (props.series.user_id == props.user) : false);
    const cover = "https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/" + props.book.isbn + "-M.jpg";
    const [read, setRead] = useState(props.book.read);
    const [mySeries, setMySeries] = useState([]);
    const [showAddTo, setShowAddTo] = useState(false);
    const [isMySeriesFetched, setIsMySeriesFetched] = useState(false);
    const [inThisSeries, setInThisSeries] = useState(props.book.in_this_series);

    function addBook (series) {
        // first add the book if necessary
        console.log('book id ' + props.book.id);
        if (props.book.id == '') {
            console.log('adding book to database');
            console.log(props.book);

            axios.post(route('api.book.store'), props.book)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                addToSeries(response.data.id);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        } else {
            addToSeries(series);
        }
    }

    function addToSeries(book) {
        console.log('adding book to series');
        axios.post(route('api.series.addbook', {series: props.series.id, book: book}), props.book)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            props.added(props.book.id);
            setInThisSeries(true);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    function removeBook() {
        console.log('removing book from series');
        console.log(props.book);
        props.delete(props.book.id);
        setInThisSeries(false);
    }

    function toggleRead() {
        setRead(!read);

        axios.post(route('api.book.changeread', {book: props.book.id}), {read: !read})
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            setRead(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    function getMySeries() {
        console.log('getting MySeries');
        axios.get(route('api.series.index'))
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                setMySeries(response.data.mySeries);
                setShowAddTo(true);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    let seriesList = mySeries.length > 0
        ? mySeries.map((s, i) => {
            return (
                <div key={i}>
                    <Checkbox
                        onChange={() => addBook(s.id)}></Checkbox>
                    {s.name}
                </div>
            );
        })
        : <p>Create a new list</p>;

    return (
        <div className="card">
            <Image key={cover} coverUrl={cover} fallbackUrl="/storage/nocover.png" />
            <div className="details">
                <p className="name p-0">{props.book.title}</p>
                <p>by {props.book.author}</p>
                <p className="isbn">
                    ISBN: {props.book.isbn}
                </p>
                <p>In {props.book.series_count ? props.book.series_count : 0} list{props.book.series_count != 1 && 's'}</p>
                {props.user != 0 && props.book.id &&
                    <p>
                        <span className="middle inline-block mr-2">
                            <Switch isOn={read} handleToggle={toggleRead} />
                        </span>
                        <span className="middle">{read ? "I've read this" : "Yet to read"}</span>
                    </p>
                }
                <div className="grow"></div>
                <div className="buttons flex">
                    <Link href={route('author.show', props.book.author_key)}>
                        <PrimaryButton className="blue" title="See more books by author">
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPerson} />
                        </PrimaryButton>
                    </Link>
                    {props.book.id &&
                        <Link href={route('book.show', props.book.id)}>
                            <PrimaryButton className="blue" title="See all lists containing this book">
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} rotation={90} />
                            </PrimaryButton>
                        </Link>
                    }
                    {props.user != 0 && isOwner && hasSeries && (
                      inThisSeries ? (
                        <Link href="#">
                            <PrimaryButton className="red" onClick={removeBook} title="Remove this book from the list">
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} />
                            </PrimaryButton>
                        </Link>
                      ) : (
                        <Link href="#">
                            <PrimaryButton className="green" onClick={() => addBook(props.book.id)} title="Add this book to the list">
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />
                            </PrimaryButton>
                        </Link>
                      )
                    )}
                    {props.user != 0 && props.allowAddTo &&
                        <PrimaryButton className="green" onClick={() => getMySeries()} title="Add this book to a list"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} /></PrimaryButton>
                    }
                    {showAddTo &&
                        seriesList
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

If I exclude the  tags, I see 8 books. If I include the tags, I see the text saying 'This series has no books yet.' But the console still shows 16 instances of the list with 8 books. Also adding {bookList.length} into my return statement shows the length of the list is 8 even while the text for an empty list is displayed.

Before I go and learn how to build my own draggable component, can anyone point me in the right direction to fix my code or suggest where I might look?